# SQL to list tables in a dashDB schema

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, db2-luw, dashdb

I need to list all of the tables in a schema in dashDB (Db2 Warehouse on Cloud on IBM Cloud).

Is this possible using just a SQL statement or do I need a CLI tool for this?

If it is possible using a SQL statement, please let me know what it is.

Please DON'T provide the CLI statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do:

```
select tabname from syscat.tables
where tabschema='yourSpecificSchemaName'
```

Note that information like the above can be found in the [Knowledge Center for dashDB in the roadmap to catalog views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011297.html). The view used above is [SYSCAT.TABLES](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html).